# Mathematical Definition of Entropy and a Question about the Nature of Stat. Mechanics Approach

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, entropy, statistical-mechanics

I have been studying for quite some time now about entropic functionals, including *Boltzmann-Gibbs, Renyi, Kaniadakis* and *Tsallis*, and I am familiar with the properties that a functional has to fulfill in order for it to represent the entropy of a system.

But I am more interested to find the detailed mathematical way in which these entropic functionals are defined. I would like to know the strict mathematical definition of an entropic funtional.

For example, for *Boltzmann-Gibbs*, $S_{BG}=-k\sum p_i \ln p_i$, or *Tsallis* entropy $S_q=\left( 1-\sum p_i^q \right)/(q-1)$:

- Which functional space are they defined in?
- What are the properties of that space? *(norm, metric, boundeness, completeness,
  etc)*

Is there a detailed report/analysis answering these questions?

Finally, I have the following question. Given the foundations of classical statistical mechanics, it comes to my understanding that in order to study the microstates of the system we start with *Newton's* law, therefore a **deterministic** approach. But in the thermodynamical limit, we end up with probability density functions, therefore a **stochastic** approach.

What are the conditions that have to be met in order for these two, in general contradictory approaches, to coexist?

I have been quite buffled by the above.

Thank you.

Comment: See [KL Divergence Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)

Comment: @AHusain Thank you for your answer. But that reference does not clarify almost anything of my question. I would say it could confuse me a bit more. I just want to know how one entropic functional is defined.

Comment: there is no problem for describing a deterministic system by a stochastic model. for example if you know the deterministic time evolution of $10^{23}$ small balls in a (adiabatic) box, and that you look at $r_i(t)$ the position of the $i$th ball at time $t$, once you say that the initial positions and velocities are random variables, then $r_i(t)$ is also a random variable, and you can say rigorously that as $t \to \infty$, $r_i(t) \to$ to the uniform distribution quite fast.

Comment: @user1952009 Therefore you are saying we cross the line between determinism and stochasticity once the number of "particles" or balls as you say is large enough. Ofc I do get that "large enough" is a blurred way to put it, but still I am after the concept behind it. Is the way I see it correct?

Comment: No, I said once we replace one of the deterministic parameter of the system by a random variable, for example the initial position/velocity of the particles (I said balls because it is a very Newtonian deterministic object)

Comment: @user1952009 But, is this logical? Can we just swap the deterministic parameter with a stochastic one and still have the same system as before?

Comment: No, I said once we replace one of the deterministic parameter of the system by a random variable, for example the initial position/velocity of the particles (I said balls because it is a very Newtonian deterministic object). Now when the number of particles become very large, you often say that this number is unknown and follows some probability distribution (it becomes a random variable),  in that case all the measurements you can do on the system become random variables too.

Comment: It is not because we introduced some random variables that the equations will change. The equations stay the same, applying to each of possible values of the random variables separately. The trick is then to introduce an equation based on the probability distributions, and yes those are totally new and different equations, for example the [Boltzmann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation).

Comment: @user1952009 I see. So I can have both deterministic and stochastic approach. But there must exist some specific conditions that have to be met in order for this "both approach" way to be doable. Which are these?